# Using jQuery slide/animate to move a centered item to left while sliding in div from right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

The title isn't the best, but what I'd like to accomplish is to move a center login box to the left **and** slide in div from right upon anchor tag push.  Basically moving centered box to a left 'column' (for lack of a better word) and slide a div into frame from the right, into the right 'column'.

Here is a basic jsFiddle example of what I have so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/g794j09o/1/

Unfortunately I have two issues I'm having trouble with:

1. How to line up the `moreInfo` div outside the frame without allowing scroll and maintaining the centered `loginBox`.
2. How to properly use the jQuery slide/animate features to slide the `loginBox` to the only to left a little, while sliding in the entire `moreInfo` box.

I have looked around SO for other jQuery slide/animate questions and have found them to be helpful for learning how to animate something, but I'm having issues solving everything from the CSS side of things.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you was just sliding the 'moreInfo' div where in fact you should have been showing and sliding the div instead of "Hiding the div out of the frame", you have clearly done some kind of animation before but you should read up on web programming as you are referring to "Frames" etc. (p.s i recommend MVA for learning new topics)

Anyway this is the Jquery, it is not perfect but this should give you the stepping stone you are looking for:

```
$("#moreInfo").click(function() {
    $("#divLogin").animate({ marginLeft: "-387px"} , 1000);
    setTimeout(divmoreinfo, 2000);
});

function divmoreinfo() {
     $("#divLogin").addClass('divLoginFloat');
     $("#divMoreInfo").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1400);    
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjardine/g794j09o/5/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to build off this.  The only thing that concerns me is the `show` for `divMoreInfo` automatically pushes the `divLogin` over like a stutter instead of slides it.  Maybe I can actually, perform the `divLogin` slide before the `show divMoreInfo`.

I knew Frame wasn't the perfect word to describe what I was trying to say, but it fit close enough.

Comment: @atschaal please see updated version, working as you asked. P.S if this helps then please mark as the accepted answer :)

Comment: I also modified the jsfiddle to do this.  It's still not what I want, once the `show` activates, the divLogin still jumps.  I think I'm going to have to do this with widths or something.

Comment: It doesnt jump on my JSFiddle? @atschaal

Comment: It definitely does, I'm sorry.  I've found a better way to do it.
http://jsfiddle.net/tVHYg/1508/